ASP.NET Core Razor page asp-page-handler calling layout?
I am trying to export list of DTOs to Excel in .csv format.
It generates this HTML in the browser:
<form method="post" action="/Modules/Payroll/Employee?handler=_ExportCSV">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>&nbsp;Export to CSV
    </button>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="...">
</form>

When clicking the 'Export to CSV' button, it is first calling _PayrollLayout.cshtml and as Viewdata is null, I get an error instead of .csv file.
I have tried to debug using but it is giving me error every time.

“Viewdata is null” shows that there was a problem with data transfer or data binding. Could you kindly provide the code of _ExportCSV handler and a detailed error description?

Since you only provided the .cshtml code, I can only write a sample example to achieve the functionality you want.
Below is my test example:
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

Employee.cshtml:
@page
@model EmployeeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employee";
}

<h2>Employee List</h2>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="ExportCSV">
    <input type="hidden" id="dtoList" name="dtoList" value='@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.DtoList))' />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>&nbsp;Export to CSV
    </button>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>

Employee.cshtml.cs:
public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Employee> DtoList { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Initialize the list of DTOs (can be obtained from a database or other source)
        DtoList = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Salary = 50000 },
            new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Smith", Salary = 55000 }
        };
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostExportCSV(string dtoList)
    {
        DtoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(dtoList);

        if (DtoList == null || !DtoList.Any())
        {
            return BadRequest("no data to export");
        }

        var csvContent = GenerateCSV(DtoList);

        var csvBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
        var csvStream = new MemoryStream(csvBytes);

        return File(csvStream, "text/csv", "data.csv");
    }

    private string GenerateCSV(List<Employee> dtoList)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("Id,Name,Salary");

        foreach (var dto in dtoList)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{dto.Id},{dto.Name},{dto.Salary}");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

My test result:


@kakss Please post new questions as questions (the big blue "Ask Question" button at the top right of the page), not as new answers.

Hi, @kakss. Did you solve this problem by referring to the example I provided? If you have new questions, you can post a new one as suggested by TylerH.

Asked a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78959511/handler-is-calling-layout-page-and-get-method
