Handler is calling _Layout page and Get() method
When calling a handler from cshtml page (using Razor project) why it is doing full page refresh by going to public void OnGet() method and then it go to public IActionResult OnPostExportCSV(int id)? I was thinking by callling the hadler ExportCSV it will directly goto call OnPostExportCSV(int id)
Also found out first character of hander must be between 'A to Z', as mine was '_ExportCSV' it is invalid.
Expected to directly call the Handler like AJAX call, but by calling Handler it is calling _Layout - I want to just call a method on server side nothing else.

See Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78944445/asp-net-core-razor-page-asp-page-handler-calling-layout/78947265

Please don’t post a new question if it’s the same issue, or if it’s a new issue please include all necessary code and information in this question. Currently it’s impossible to say anything since there’s no code to evaluate.

Sami, thank you, I am leaning Stack Overflow.


When calling a handler from cshtml page (using Razor project) why it is doing full page refresh by going to public void OnGet() method and then it go to public IActionResult OnPostExportCSV(int id)? I was thinking by callling the hadler ExportCSV it will directly goto call OnPostExportCSV(int id)

When calling a handler, a form POST request is sent to the server, and calls the OnPostExportCSV method. If OnPostExportCSV returns a file download, it typically does not trigger a page reload. The browser will handle the file download without refreshing the page. However, if the form submission leads to a page refresh due to browser behavior, then OnGet might be called.
OnGet to initialize state needed for the page. OnPost to handle form submissions.
The handler, specified by the asp-page-handler attribute. When the button is selected, a form POST request is sent to the server. By convention, the name of the handler method is selected based on the value of the handler parameter according to the scheme OnPost[handler]Async.
You can learn more details in this doc.

Expected to directly call the Handler like AJAX call, but by calling Handler it is calling _Layout - I want to just call a method on server side nothing else.

You can use the Ajax call to achieve this.

Yumiao, Thank you. I want to reply as a comment in this thread, but I am not sure how do I do that? Can you able to help?

This comment is replied correctly to my answer, and if you want to add a comment to reply to the comments under your question, you can click the link "Add a comment" under your question.

Yes Yumiao, thank you. What I don't know is how to put another thread or conversation topics?

Put another thread as a link is ok, or you can provide the related code for the methods you mentioned in the question.

Yumiao, thank you and no worries. Will try next time.
